# Windows XP connection limits & FTP Server?

Tags: windows-xp, ftp

I'm looking to set up an FTP Server and have a spare XP box that I want to use.  I know XP limits user connections to 10?  Will this affect the number of FTP users who can login at the same time?

Also, I'm using a 3rd party FTP server so I don't need to issue Windows accounts for any of the FTP clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per microsoft "The TCP connection limit is not enforced, but it may be bound by legal agreement to not permit more than 10 clients."

Edit: Source - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314882

The section that I quoted was from their development part, but thats why other tools such as a non-microsoft ftp will work.

Answer (score -1):

If its a 3rd party software that is handling the logins and not IIS, then XPs user limit should not come into play at all.

Comment: Windows may not enforce the limit, but legally you're limited to 10 client connections.

Comment: I realize there is an "ethical" limit, but the question that was asked was if it would affect the number of users logged in. The answer, is "No"